# How to access the settings in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way to, from my code to access the iOS settings app for a certain setting? For example I want to know if "WiFi" is turned on or not? Or even be able to change the settings?

Comment: i want to access the general settings, not the address book settings

Comment: If these settings can be accessed programmatically consider the havoc it would cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is jailbreak than you can access the settings otherwise it is restricted to access the settings in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to check that internet connection is available or not using Apple Reachebility API but its not possible to change any kinda setting programatically.

Comment: Is there any possibility that i can open the settings by clicking the button in my app?

Comment: Till iOS 5.0 it was possible to open settings via the URL schema,
This has been deprecated from iOS 5.1 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but if your application run on a jailbroken phone then only it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Before Apple released iOS 5 the only way to quickly access specific iOS settings was by jailbreaking the device and using SBSettings. With iOS 5 Apple included a special URL scheme, for example “prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK”, to enable direct access to the settings.

Finally, here’s a list of the currently available URLs:

1. prefs:root=General&path=About
2. prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
3. prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
4. prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
5. prefs:root=General&path=USAGE/CELLULAR_USAGE
6. prefs:root=Brightness
7. prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
8. prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
9. prefs:root=FACETIME
10. prefs:root=General
11. prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
12. prefs:root=CASTLE
13. prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
14. prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
15. prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
16. prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
17. prefs:root=MUSIC
18. prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
19. prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
20. prefs:root=General&path=Network
21. prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
22. prefs:root=NOTES
23. prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
24. prefs:root=Phone
25. prefs:root=Photos
26. prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
27. prefs:root=General&path=Reset
28. prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone
29. prefs:root=Safari
30. prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
31. prefs:root=Sounds
32. prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
33. prefs:root=STORE
34. prefs:root=TWITTER
35. prefs:root=General&path=USAGE
36. prefs:root=VIDEO
37. prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
38. prefs:root=Wallpaper
39. **prefs:root=WIFI**
40. prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING